# Developping software using Google Pixel Buds bluetooth headset

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, microphone

I am currently developping a piece of software that requires a microphone and some way to "click"... that is why I was enthusiastic using Google pixel buds.

I can use the buds microphone with python sounddevice library as soon as I set them as my Input device in Ubuntu Settings > Sound > Input device.

I can retrieve the simple, double click or triple click signal on the buds from device /dev/input/event19 using evdev library. Signal are PLAY_PAUSE (200) NEXT_TRACK(163) and PREV_TRACK (165) but ..... it workds only when it is not set set as Input device in Ubuntu Settings > Sound > Input device.

This is so frustrating to have the two pieces of code working but that can't work together !

Do you please have an idea how I could make this work ? The buds themselves can do it as your can double click on the bud during a phone conversation to end the call.

Thanks
Christophe

Comment: The microphone is not a sharable resource. Only one process may have the microphone open at a time.